# Shading/Highlighting partial text using Apache FOP 0.20.5 and converting to PDF

Tags: background-color, highlight, partial, apache-fop

I am using FO file to shade/highlight a part of the entire text and render in PDF format using Apache FOP 0.20.5

But the background-color given to the last inline element (<fo:inline background-color=”#DADADA#”>Three</fo:inline>) with in the fo:block gets applied to the whole block

FO file is passed as input to Apache FOP 0.20.5 as input , and FOP converts it into PDF file.

Sample structure:

```
<fo:block>
<fo:inline>One</fo:inline>
<fo:inline>Two</fo:inline>
<fo:inline background-color=”#DADADA#”>Three</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

FO example:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="first" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".25in" margin-right=".25in">
<fo:region-body/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
<fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
<fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first"/>
</fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" force-page-count="no-force" initial-page-number="1">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" text-align="left" span="all" font-family="Courier" font-size="10pt" color="#000000" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="no-underline no-line-through">
This is just a simple test sentence.Next sentence has to be highlighted
<fo:inline background-color="#DADADA"> This part of sentence has to be highlighted</fo:inline>
</fo:block>

</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>`
```

Highlighting is done as:
[image: Highlighting is done as:]

I tried different formats as below , but one of them worked:
Eg: 1:

```
`<fo:block>
<fo:inline background-color=”#DADADA#”>One</fo:inline>
<fo:inline>Two</fo:inline>
<fo:inline >Three</fo:inline>
</fo:block>`
```

Eg 2:

```
<fo:inline-container>
<fo:block>
<fo:inline>One</fo:inline>
<fo:inline>Two</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:inline-container>
<fo:inline background-color=”#DADADA#”>Three</fo:inline>
```

1.How to highlight/shade only the text Three without shading One Two.

2. I am dealing with legacy application that cannot upgrade to Latest FOP versions. Could there be any change required in this FO file for it to highlight only a part of the text while converting to PDF